# Duvidas sobre funções

Tags: python, funções, modularização

Esse meu código simula operações bancárias usando funções, porém não estou conseguindo retornar os valores da função, quando eu seto o valor do return numa variável ele chama a toda a função.
No programa quando eu chamo a função 'saldo', ele me retorna a função 'deposito' e não ao valor de 'montante'.

Alguma orientação? Como eu posso fazer isso? Há uma forma melhor?

```
def deposito(dep):
    clear()
    montante=0.0
    dep=0.0
    dep=float(input("Quantia a ser depositada:"))
    clear()
    if (dep > 0):
        print (" |",montante)
        print ("+|",dep)
        montante=montante+dep
        print ("____________")
        print (" |",montante,"\n\n")
    else:
        print("Quantia inválida")
    voltar()
    return montante

def saldo():
    saldo=deposito()
    print("O seu saldo é:", saldo())


def main():
    op=0
    while(op != range(0,4,1)):
        clear()
        print("Qual tipo de operação deseja realizar?\n")
        print ("[1]Saldo")
        print ("[2]Depósito")
        print ("[3]Saque")
        print ("[0]Sair\n")
        op=str(input(""))


        if(op == "1"):
            saldo()
        elif(op == "2"):
            deposito()
        elif(op == "3"):
            saque()
        elif(op == "0"):
            exit
        else:
            clear()
            print("Operação inválida")
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Eu acho que o código está com alguns problemas na formatação. Pelo menos no meu celular a função `deposito` e seu primeiro comando estão no mesmo nível de indentação

Comment: Se você quer saber se `op` não está no intervalo que varia [0,4), sua condição do `while` da função `main` não está fazendo isso

Comment: `saldo` está em recursão infinita? Na verdade eu não consigo prever o comportamento do Python nesse caso, apesar de que eu acho que ele vai falar que o parâmetro `dep` não tem valor padrão, ou que `float` não é executável

Comment: Reforçando o que o @JeffersonQuesado disse, confirme que a identação do código aqui na pergunta é a mesma que tem. Se for não está correta.

Comment: Dei rollback na edição que aplicou identação, tendo em vista que ela, se não for feita corretamente, pode afetar o funcionamento do código em python.

Comment: Feito a correção de identação do código aqui, no programa está correto.

Answer (score 1):

As funções que tem não estão a ser definidas/chamadas corretamente, assim como tem outros erros pequenos de construção.

- No topo foi definida a função `deposito` para que receba um valor:

  ```
  def deposito(dep):
  ```

  Este valor `dep` não é passado no main onde é chamada esta função:

  ```
  elif(op == "2"):
      deposito()
  ```

  Tem duas opções ou lê o valor no `main` e passa à função `deposito`, ou não passa nenhum valor e lê o valor dentro da função `deposito`. Neste momento você está a fazer as duas. A correção mais simples será retirar o parametro da definição da função, deixando-a como:

  ```
  def deposito():
  ```
- Na função `saldo` está a pegar num `float` e tentar utiliza-lo como se fosse uma função

  ```
  def saldo():
      saldo=deposito()
      print("O seu saldo é:", saldo()) #<-- aqui em saldo()
  ```

  A função `deposito()` retorna um `float` logo basta mostrar esse `float` diretamente, assim:

  ```
  print("O seu saldo é:", saldo) #agora sem os ()
  ```
- O `montante` não é global as funções todas logo não irá acumular à medida que executa as várias operações. Para o tornar global precisa de o colocar antes da função e utilizar a palavra reservada `global` dentro da função:

  ```
  montante = 0.0

  ...

  def deposito():
      clear()
      global montante #aqui indica que está a utilizar o montante global fora da função
  ```